# Httpclienthandler Webproxy value isn't changing

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-framework-version

Could someone help me. I have a little problem of setting the boolean property to true.

Here I created a class for my proxy so that I can set and call from my winform to my httpclient class.

```
class MyProxy
{
    public static bool UseProxy { get; set; }
    public static string ProxyHost { get; set; } = string.Empty; 
    public static string ProxyPort { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}
```

and here's the optional if I want to use proxy or not

```
private static HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler
{
    UseDefaultCredentials = false,
    PreAuthenticate = true,
    Proxy = new WebProxy($"http://{MyProxy.ProxyHost}:{MyProxy.ProxyPort}", false),
    UseProxy = MyProxy.UseProxy, // i want to change this if I want to use the proxy or not
};
```

So in my main form, I have a checkbox whether use proxy or not

```
private void TEST()
{
  bool isCheck = cbUseProxy.Checked;
  
  //so here I'll check first if isCheck is true
  MyProxy.UseProxy = isCheck;
  
  //here I call my httpclient class
}
```

The problem is, if I set first or check first the checkbox (which is useProxy) the Webproxy is getting the value. and I uncheck (which is not to use proxy) the webproxy still getting the first value (which is true).

I want to change from true to false and false to true the value of UseProxy (from WebProxy).

UPDATED FINAL SOLUTION: (thanks to @Milney for the suggestion. I think this is the solution)

```
private static HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler
        {
            PreAuthenticate = true,
            UseDefaultCredentials = false,
            Proxy = null,
            UseProxy = false,
        };
        private static HttpClientHandler handlerWithProxy = new HttpClientHandler
        {
            PreAuthenticate = true,
            UseDefaultCredentials = false,
            Proxy = new WebProxy($"http://{MyProxy.ProxyHost}:{MyProxy.ProxyPort}", false),
            UseProxy = true,
        };

        private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
        private static readonly HttpClient clientWithProxy = new HttpClient(handlerWithProxy);
```

and then on my ResponseMessage

```
     private static async Task<JsonDocument> ResponseMessage(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken token)
        {
            HttpCompletionOption option = HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead;
            bool useProxy = MyProxy.UseProxy;

            using (var response = useProxy ? await clientWithProxy.SendAsync(request, option, token).ConfigureAwait(false) 
                                           : await client.SendAsync(request, option, token).ConfigureAwait(false))
            {
                token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

                using (var contentStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().ConfigureAwait(false))
                {
                    var json = await ParseJsonFromStream(contentStream);

                    if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        if (json != null)
                        {
                            throw new InvalidDataException($"Error occured: {ParseError(uri, json)}");
                        }
                    }
                    return json;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: What is your _question_? Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63651387/edit) so that it includes a [mcve] that demonstrates whatever problem you have. Also include a clear description of what that code does, what you want it to do instead, and what _specifically_ you need help with.

Comment: Do you have all these code snippets in the same class? Did you get an error message from your compiler? If yes what is the message?

Comment: @Steve yes the snippets is in the same class. my only error is if useProxy isn't detected my request isn't proceed. and if I manually set useProxy to true and I can get the response successfuly.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I have updated my question and code as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the time you create the HttpClientHandler, the MyProxy.UseProxy has its default value.
If you change it later on it won't automatically 'flow' through to the client handler properties. You'll need to recreate your HttpClientHandler, or atleast reset the property on it AFTER you actually get the value you want to use...

```
private void TEST()
{
  bool isCheck = cbUseProxy.Checked;
  
  // You have to set the property on the handler
  // It won't automatically refresh from your other class
  handler.UseProxy = isCheck;   

  //here I call my httpclient class
}
```

Comment: Oh I get it. That's why If I set first to true, proxy is working and if I set to false the proxy still working. Maybe this is my problem that's why the property isn't changing.

But, the problem is how I can recreate new httpclienthandler. Because this is my httpclient:  private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);

Comment: Just create a new HttpClient then

Comment: I don't want to re-create my httpclient in every request. How it's possible to make new handler and put in on httpclient

Comment: You can't. You could create two, one with the proxy and one without - then use your flag to determine which one to send the request with. But you can't actually modify it after creation, to ensure that multiple threads can use it safely

Comment: Ah Oh I see. I think that's better idea to create two options with and without proxy. Thank you so much.

Comment: Note that although you can't change the Handler after creating the HttpClient - I think you can change the client.DefaultProxy property, which will be applied to all requests if you DONT provide a handler. So you could also try it that way, but that only applies to the proxy settings - not the other handler settings

Comment: Could you check my updated code if this is what you are talking about?

Comment: Yeah that should work, then just do if(isCheck) clientWithProxy.DoRequest() else client.DoRequest()

Comment: @what do you mean, Proxy settings of my Windows Proxy Settings? so that's the other way to call the proxy?